# provide php function params in address bar

Tags: php

How can I call this by passing the parameters in the address bar?

The code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Generate the list of pages, linking to each
 *
 * @param integer $boardpage Current board page
 * @param integer $pages Number of pages
 * @param string $board Board directory
 * @return string Generated page list
 */

/* <3 coda for this wonderful snippet
print $contents to $filename by using a temporary file and renaming it */
function print_page($filename, $contents, $board) {
    global $tc_db;

    $tempfile = tempnam(KU_BOARDSDIR . $board . '/res', 'tmp'); /* Create the temporary file */
    $fp = fopen($tempfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $contents);
    fclose($fp);
    /* If we aren't able to use the rename function, try the alternate method */
    if (!@rename($tempfile, $filename)) {
        copy($tempfile, $filename);
        unlink($tempfile);
    }

    chmod($filename, 0664); /* it was created 0600 */
}

?>
```

this is what I tried:

> http://example.com/inc/func/pages.php?action=print_page&$filename%27lel.php&$contents=%27asdasd%27&$board=b

but that is clearly not working to call the method. Ideas?
Im not actually attempting to call it for any purpose of my own. someone used RCE on my website to upload a shell and deface it. This is the only vulnerable method I can find using grep. All exec and system methods are washed and safe. Other ideas?

Comment: Based on your comment on J-Dizzle' answer, are there any upload functions present?

Comment: there are, I will have to find them.

Comment: Do you run the uploaded files against a whitelist?

Comment: No, we do the opposite. for flagged files we check uploads against banned md5 hashes

Comment: Have you tried an example attack on your own site to see if this is where they exploited? **example** - `http://example.com/inc/func/pages.php?action=print_page&$filename%27lel.php&$contents=<?php echo '<h1>uwotm8</h1>'; ?>&$board=b`. or even encoding it?

Comment: Darren, I've been trying things like that on every function and param that I could find. I've looked at several files and functions, read articles, but bottom line is I am a novice programmer, not a security expert. Feelsbadman.

Comment: We all start someone mate, have you tried encoding the `<?` and doing something like `%3C%3Fphp base64_decode(ZWNobyAnPGgxPkRFUlA8L2gxPic7); %3F%3E`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you call the function with

```
print_page($_REQUEST['filename'], $_REQUEST['contents'], $_REQUEST['board'])
```

Comment: Im not actually attempting to call it for any purpose of my own. someone used RCE on my website to upload a shell and deface it. This is the only vulnerable method I can find using grep. All exec and system methods are washed and safe. Other ideas?

Comment: Oh, so your question wasn't your question? Interesting. So glad I could help.

Comment: Actually my question was quite literally my question. how to feed them to the address bar. as-is.